# Magento Change Handling Fee Algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, magento

I am using Magento 1.8.1 and I have a serious problem: the handling fee is being calculated as a percentage of the total shipping. Instead, I need this fee to be calculated as a percentage of the shopping cart subtotal (without the shipping price). Right now for a $100 cart with shipping costs of $10 and a handling fee of 10% the fee is being calculated as $1 (10% of shipping) for a grand total of $111. Instead, we need the handling fee to be 10% of the cart for a grand total of $120.

How can we make this happen? I found that the file for the algorithm is in app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php
and the lines are 460-468

```
/**
 * Calculate price considering free shipping and handling fee
 *
 * @param string $cost
 * @param string $method
 * @return float|string
 */
public function getMethodPrice($cost, $method = '')
{
    return $method == $this->getConfigData($this->_freeMethod)
        && $this->getConfigFlag('free_shipping_enable')
        && $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal') <= $this->_rawRequest->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()
        ? '0.00'
        : $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost);
}

/**
 * Get the handling fee for the shipping + cost
 *
 * @param float $cost
 * @return float final price for shipping method
 */
public function getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost)
{
    $handlingFee = $this->getConfigData('handling_fee');
    $handlingType = $this->getConfigData('handling_type');
    if (!$handlingType) {
        $handlingType = self::HANDLING_TYPE_FIXED;
    }
    $handlingAction = $this->getConfigData('handling_action');
    if (!$handlingAction) {
        $handlingAction = self::HANDLING_ACTION_PERORDER;
    }

    return $handlingAction == self::HANDLING_ACTION_PERPACKAGE
        ? $this->_getPerpackagePrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee)
        : $this->_getPerorderPrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee);
}

/**
 * Get final price for shipping method with handling fee per package
 *
 * @param float $cost
 * @param string $handlingType
 * @param float $handlingFee
 * @return float
 */
protected function _getPerpackagePrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee)
{
    if ($handlingType == self::HANDLING_TYPE_PERCENT) {
        return ($cost + ($cost * $handlingFee/100)) * $this->_numBoxes;
    }

    return ($cost + $handlingFee) * $this->_numBoxes;
}

/**
 * Get final price for shipping method with handling fee per order
 *
 * @param float $cost
 * @param string $handlingType
 * @param float $handlingFee
 * @return float
 */
protected function _getPerorderPrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee)
{
    if ($handlingType == self::HANDLING_TYPE_PERCENT) {
        return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + ($cost * $this->_numBoxes * $handlingFee / 100);
    }

    return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + $handlingFee;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the file `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php` into `app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php` (note the codepool - **local**)

```
protected function _getPerorderPrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee)
{
    if ($handlingType == self::HANDLING_TYPE_PERCENT) {
        if($cost) { //if shipping is not free
            $cartTotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
            return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + ($cartTotal["subtotal"]->getValue() * $handlingFee / 100);   
        } else {  //if shipping is free
              return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + ($cost * $this->_numBoxes * $handlingFee / 100);
     }

  return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes) + $handlingFee;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rakesh Shewale for your answer. Everything works fine except the fact that the free shipping now generates percentage from the subtotal and it isn't really free. Can you help me with that
?

Comment: I've updated the answer.. I have not tested the code, so you may need to make some minor changes if any error occurs :)

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't work. Can you make the code to do this:

if shipping price is 0.00 than remove handling fee?

Comment: did you try making such change? i mean instead of if($cost) try if($cost  > 0)

Comment: With the code you gave me now I get an error. With the first code everything worked fine... So I can't try to change the if($cost) to ($cost > 0) cause it won't work... If you help me I will really appreciate that. I can donate you if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, however, on this forum I am interested in helping programmers for free :) Please let me know what exactly did not work

Comment: I get Error 500 Internal Server Error

Internal Server Error

Guru Meditation:

XID: 1030439461

Comment: on line 51
2015-06-26T08:54:34+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _category  in /app/design/frontend/default/galayomarket/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 208, I guess I have a syntax error in the php file causing the problem

Comment: You said it worked with the first code.. then it must work with this code also. I guess, you've made some other changes, can you undo all other changes and bring it back to that situation again(where it worked without error)?

Comment: I made it working man. I dont know how to thank you. You are really great person! I was missing one more } at the end of the code. Thank you so much! I really appreciate your work.

Comment: I am so glad I could be of some help to you :) Happy coding

Comment: Now I have another problem waiting for solution. If you can help me, I will really appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875604/magento-hide-other-shipping-methods-if-shipping-price-is-0-00-without-module